# Execute formatting on multiple excel files

Tags: excel, formatting

I'm trying to code up a way to do the following to multiple .csv files:

1. Highlight a set of columns
2. Select home/conditional formatting/color scales/{2nd option}
3. Save the result as a .xls file (to maintain the color scaling)

Any tips on how to write this up, and execute it on multiple files?  I've never really tried to program excel to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to a technique I've used, you should be able to adapt it to your needs, there is a sample file for you try it on. It even includes a UDF that will create folders for you.

[**CSVs to Workbooks**](https://sites.google.com/a/madrocketscientist.com/jerrybeaucaires-excelassistant/conversions/csvs-to-wbs)

In the code you'll see these two lines:

```
ActiveSheet.Name = NwName       'rename the sheet
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fPath & NwName & ".xls", FileFormat:=xlNormal
```

Slip your *formatting* code in there, changing it to something like:

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Name = NwName       'rename the sheet
    .Range("A:G").NumberFormat = "General"
    .Range("A:G").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    With .Range("F2:F10000").SpecialCells(xlConstants)
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=F9>50"
        .FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
    End With
End With
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fPath & NwName & ".xls", FileFormat:=xlNormal
```

That should get you started.